# How does BSP looks like in Embedded Linux?

Tags: c, linux, yocto, device-tree, bsp

I am Embedded Developer (fresher) by profession. I have written firmware (in C and C++) for ARM Cortex-M, PIC, Atmel 8-bit controller. I am aware of the source code management and that's why I used to have Board Specific, Compiler Specific information in different `C header files`.

I have written firmware for custom boards which had same microcontroller (PIC24F) but their on-board peripherals, debug interface, LEDs, buttons and other stuff keeps on changing across various versions of the boards. So, I used to have a BSP folder which contains header files for each of the board and a top level header file which includes a specific header file based on macros (one macro for each board). Then, a config header files define one macro to enable all the required peripherals, configuration for one specific board.

[image]

The BSP header files looks like this:

[image]

And the final board specific header file looks like this:

[image]

Now, I am working on `yocto project` and `device tree`. I am wondering how BSP actually looks like in yocto project and embedded linux. Is it just `device tree` which contains board specific, SoC specific and may be Core specific information? Or There is something more to it?

I know this question could be considered as `TOO BOARD` but what I am looking for is a brief overview of the BSP structure in Yocto Project or Embedded Linux. Pointers to specific directors or online links will be really helpful to get started. I have tried google few times but didn't find a concise picture of it. Please help.

Comment: I assume that following manual may help https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/1.8/bsp-guide/bsp-guide.html

Comment: Yep. TOO BOARD :)   Different people define BSP differently, from just a minimal set of files to run the board, to a very usable package such as Raspberry Pi has.